# Numerical Recipes in fortran 90 ran_init integer model assumption

Tags: integer, fortran, numerical-recipes

The `ran_init` subrroutine of the Numerical Recipes contains this lines:

```
INTEGER(K4B) :: new,j,hgt
...                                                                                            
hgt=hg 
...
if (hgt+1 /= hgng)    call nrerror('ran_init: arith assump 3 fails')
```

Where `K4B`, `hgng` and `hg` are globally declared in the module via:

```
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: K4B=selected_int_kind(9) 
INTEGER(K4B), PARAMETER :: hg=huge(1_K4B), hgm=-hg, hgng=hgm-1
```

The problem is that in one particular computer (but not in the others) I get the error `ran_init: arith assump 3 fails`. The only thing that I get from the documentation about this error is:

> Bit of dirty laundry here! We are testing whether the most positive
>   integer hg wraps around to the most negative integer hgng when 1 is
>   added to it. We can’t just write hg+1 , since some compilers will
>   evaluate this at compile time and return an overflow error message. 
>   If  your compiler  sees  through the charade  of  the  temporary
>   variable hgt ,  you’ll have  to  find another way to  trick  it!

How can I trick it?

Comment: perhaps this might be of interest: https://www.myroms.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=1668 - especially the compiler flag `-fno-strict-overflow`

Comment: Does it fail at compile- or runtime?

Comment: @ewcz, -fno-strict-overflow did not work. Also I can not find this flag in the documentation of my compiler version (6.1.0).

Comment: @AlexanderVogt it fails in runtime. It fails because `(hgt+1 /= hgng)` becomes true.

Comment: what do you get if you `write(*,*)hgt+1,hgng` ?

Comment: @agentp I get `-2147483648 -2147483648`

Comment: perhaps a hack work around could be to internally write the values to strings and compare the strings.  You could of course just skip the check, but that could have consequences for future portability of your code.

Comment: @agentp See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=30475

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The immediate cause of the crash:

the compiler during the optimization step can easily prove that `hgt+1` and `hgng` cannot be the same and therefore it optimizes the whole condition to `.false.`. Adding two positive integers cannot create a negative integer.

You might be able to avoid it by using smaller level of optimization or by some masquerade with temporary variables which would be more elaborate then what they did in the old Numerical Recipes. You may try to use the `-fwrapv` or `-fno-strict-overflow` flag. But it is highly unsure and will work only in a given version of the compiler with certain compiler flags.

The easiest "fix" is probably just to delete the offending check. It is quite likely to work in many circumstances (and fail terribly in others).

### Explanation and solution:

What Numerical Recipes do is against the standard of Fortran. They assume that if you add 1 to the greatest integer, you get the lowest one.

This is not allowed for Fortran integers and neither is it allowed for signed integers in C. It is only allowed for unsigned integers in C and Fortran doesn't have them.

So the compiler can safely assume that adding two positive integers can never result in a negative integer. See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=30475 for thorough discussion of these optimizations.

One option is to rewrite the operations which may lead to overflow in C and use conversion to unsigned integers. I use this in the random number generator I use (based on http://www.cmiss.org/openCMISS/wiki/RandomNumberGenerationWithOpenMP):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <memory.h>

int32_t sum_and_overflow (int32_t a, int32_t b)
{
  uint32_t au, bu, su;
  int32_t s;

  memcpy(&au, &a, sizeof(a));
  memcpy(&bu, &b, sizeof(b));
  su = au + bu;
  memcpy(&s, &su, sizeof(s));
  return s;
}
```

with Fortran interface

```
interface
  function sum_and_overflow(a, b) result(res) bind(C, name="sum_and_overflow")
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    integer(c_int32_t) :: res
    integer(c_int32_t), value :: a, b
  end function
end interface
```

and instead of

```
c = a + b
```

I call

```
c =  sum_and_overflow(a, b)
```

So in your case

```
if (sum_and_overflow(hgt,1) /= hgng) ...
```

but not only there, you would have to at least one more place where is this assumption used in the generator. In the generator I use there is only one such line.

---

There are many other hacks which may lead for temporary success, but will fail later with some other compiler options. For example, the undefined behaviour sanitizations in GCC don't like overflow in signed integers in Fortran and C and will terminate your program if you do that.

This is why I try to show a solution which is more complicated, but is not working around the standard, but following it.

Comment: Hi, I've just seen this answer and I'm not sure how to resolve it for my case. I've got the same error as stated above (when trying to use the ran_state module in numerical recipes).  How exactly would I go about using your example solution, as I don't have any knowledge with using C? I assume compiling the C code into some shared object, then interfacing with Fortran and defining that interface block in the ran_state file? Apologises, for the silly question! I just want to get this resolved! Thank you!

Comment: @AlphaBetaGamma96 Honestly, the most pragmatic fix is to remove the line with the check...

Comment: Another option would be to move `hgt+1` to some Fortran function that the optimizer won't inline.

Comment: Hi Vladimir F, thanks for the quick response. I've done what you've said and the program does run now, although I get a segmenation fault now!

Comment: @AlphaBetaGamma96 That is some other problem. If you want, you can ask about it in a new question. Do not forget to include a [mcve] and enable all debuging flags in your compiler.